# How to retrieve certain characters from a string in R?

Tags: r

I have variable containing a string. I need to retrieve all the characters after certain character.

For example

```
word <- "Stackoverflow"
```

I want to retrieve "overflow". 
I know the starting position as 6, but i dont know the ending position.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for a combination of substr and nchar:

```
substr(word,6,nchar(word))
```

substr(string, beginning, end) let's you subset a string and nchar gives you the number of characters in a string.

Thanks!
Jan

Comment: this has worked. Thanks a lot. I will accept this answer in 7 minutes

Answer (score 2):

Or we can use `sub` by matching the first five characters (`.{5}`) and replacing it with `''`.

```
sub('^.{5}', '', word)
#[1] "overflow"
```